# GUI builder does not show up

Tags: codenameone, gui-builder

I'm try to make a new app with codename one using the new GUI builder. However, recently the new GUI builder failed to show up, except for the first time I create a new form.

I tried to reinstall codenameone plugin, java sdk etc. with no luck. Trying to open the gui builder in cmd with

```
java -jar C:\Users\user\.codenameone\guibuilder_1.jar
```

gave me the following

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Connector: file:/C:/Users/user/.guiBuilder/guibuilder.input
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at com.codename1.xml.Element.getChildAt(Element.java:249)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.PropertyType$38.setBodyValue(PropertyType.java:1205)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GuiPersister.createComponent(GuiPersister.java:111)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GuiPersister.createComponent(GuiPersister.java:190)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GuiPersister.load(GuiPersister.java:77)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GUIBuilder.connected(GUIBuilder.java:67)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GUIBuilder.start(GUIBuilder.java:98)
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.desktop.GUIBuilderMain$9.run(GUIBuilderMain.java:396)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1151)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:968)
        at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
        at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Codename One revisions: dd0c8959da758abcec7c88230bee90002d3f6ca3
1955

[EDT] 0:0:0,2 - Gui Builder Exception in version 1.09
[EDT] 0:0:0,3 - OS win
[EDT] 0:0:0,3 - Error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.codename1.apps.guibuilder.GUIBuilder$1.actionPerformed(GUIBuilder.java:56)
        at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:349)
        at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:977)
        at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
        at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
[EDT] 0:0:0,8 - java.lang.NullPointerException
[EDT] 0:0:0,9 - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

The same same gui forms can be opened with gui builder multiple times in another computer with no problems. Similarly, the simulator worked without problem. I wonder if this problem is caused by my system or is anyone facing the same problem?

EDIT: this is the content of guibuilder.input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<con name="App" formName="TestUI"  file="file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/my-App/res/guibuilder/com/my/App/UI/TestUI.gui" javaFile="file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/my-App/src/com/my/App/UI/TestUI.java" resFile="file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/my-App/src/theme.res" outputFile="file:/C:/Users/user/.guiBuilder/9e0d2b1d-df8d-4878-8418-f09359a7e131.ouput" running="file:/C:/Users/user/.guiBuilder/9e0d2b1d-df8d-4878-8418-f09359a7e131" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.09 is pretty old by now, we released 1.12 a while back and we released 1.13 yesterday.

I'm guessing the version in the other machine is different which is why this works correctly there.

Comment: I'm not sure how to update the gui builder or confirm the version of the builder (as a side note, the problem resolved after deleting the .gui files). However, the codename one module in eclipse should be up to date..

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you will need to wait for a plugin update. It's a bit slower to update than NetBeans/Eclipse. Newer versions have an about menu with the version number there.